# Порекомендуйте календарь на Angular

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

Я в программировании еще чайник и на JS писал календарь около 2-х месяцев, но тут познакомился с Angular и начал все приложение переписывать на нем, но не могу понять как мне мой календарь из JS файла встроить в компонент?

Возможно ли это? Или может кто посоветует уже готовое НЕ СЛОЖНОЕ решение для чайников (кроме JQuery) или подскажет как все таки инициализировать мой js файл.

В приложении на нативном JS он иннициализировался так

```
var calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.render(document.getElementById('calendar'));
```

я так понимаю что на Angular такое на прокатит=(

Comment: https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

Comment: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Comment: с этой реализацией я уже сталкивался, она ужасна. чем его доработать проще реально самому написать. в гугле я не нашел простых вариантов. я разработал вполне простой и функциональный календарик и немогу его подключить в ангуляре, это вообще реально?

Comment: если у вас есть своя реализация - то почему вы говорите что "не прокатит"? вы хоть пробовали?

Comment: Kostiantyn Okhotnyk, ваш вариант вроде похож на простой и функциональный, поюзаю отпишусь подходит он для новичков или нет=)

Comment: overthesanity она на нативном JS и я не нашел информации как его интегрировать в компонент=(

Comment: @Чайник переписать на ts, на мой взгляд это проще простого

Comment: возможно, но я к сожалению пока что не дошел до такого уровня=) я бы конечно лучше свой календарь переписал на ts так как он удобный и простой,

Comment: Календарей пруд-пруди)) Каждый себе наверное писал ... Мой: https://github.com/w3lifer/js-calendar

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbCalendar

Answer (score 0):

Вот. Прикручивай либу, там много полезных компонентов
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Почему не прокатит? Можно сделать вот так, но оговорюсь сразу - решение плохое и так делать не нужно.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Calendar } from "path.to/calendar";

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-calendar',
  templateUrl: './simple-calendar.component.html',
})
export class SimpleCalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.render(document.getElementById('calendar'));
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- simple-calendar.component.html -->
    <div id="calendar"></div>
```